# Сannot convert value of type "Obj" to expected argument type 'Obj'

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, mvvm

I have an Array that comes to me from the server.

> My problem is an error that appears when I want to add objects to an
> array. How to solve this problem and work with an array of objects
> that comes from the server ??

**EXAMPLE OF RETURNED DATA**

```
[
    {
        "empId": 1970083,
        "empCode": "2007",
        "empName": "Emp Test",
        "monthClosed": 0,
        "monthApproved": 0,
        "approvedDate": 0,
        "employerName": "Name",
        "employerApproval": 1, 
        "employerApprovalDate": "2020-09-02 17:22:51.843"
    },
]
```

This structure to receive this data

```
struct GetMonthSummaryObj: Codable {
    
    var empId: Int?
    var empCode: String?
    var empName: String?
    var monthClosed: Int?
    var monthApproved: Int?
    var approvedDate: Int?
    var employerName: String?
    var employerApproval: Int?
    var employerApprovalDate: String?
}
```

This is a method in ViewModel to add data that came to an array and use it for a table. For example, to display or the number of cells in a table

```
func setEmployees(employees: [GetMonthSummaryObj?]) {
        employeesList = []
        
        employees.forEach {_ in
            employeesList.append(CloseMonthEmpListItem(employee: employees))


 //Error - Cannot convert value of type '[GetMonthSummaryObj?]' to expected argument type 'GetMonthSummaryObj'
        }
        
    }
```

Here I create an array object to work with it

```
class CloseMonthEmpListItem: Equatable, NSCopying {

    var employee: GetMonthSummaryObj

       init(employee: GetMonthSummaryObj) {
           self.employee = employee
         
       }
    static func == (lhs: CloseMonthEmpListItem, rhs: CloseMonthEmpListItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.employee.empId == rhs.employee.empId
     }
     
     func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
         let copy = CloseMonthEmpListItem(employee: employee)
         return copy
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This  `init(employee: GetMonthSummaryObj)` accepts `GetMonthSummaryObj` type while you pass  `[GetMonthSummaryObj?]`  which won't work

You need to replace

```
employees.forEach {_ in
   employeesList.append(CloseMonthEmpListItem(employee: employees)) 
}
```

With

```
let res = employees.compactMap{ $0 }
res.forEach { item in
    employeesList.append(CloseMonthEmpListItem(employee:item)) 
}
```

or

```
let res = employees.compactMap{ $0 }
employeesList = res.map { CloseMonthEmpListItem(employee:$0) }
```

Comment: It helped, thanks. But when I connect ViewModel for cells, then there are the same errors. Tell me, can I work immediately with the array that comes, and not create another ListItems?